# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/MasterNotRunningException

Tags: java, classpath, hadoop, javac, hbase

I created by own HBase java client code, but I am having a really difficult time compiling it and getting it to run. I am compiling from the command line, and I havent been able to find any instructions how to do this, or what jars I need to have on my classpath.

Below is the classpath I'm using:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar:
$HADOOP_HOME/hbase/hbase-0.90.0/hbase-0.90.0.jar:
$HADOOP_HOME/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar
```

When I run the javac command, it compiles fine. However, when I run my java code, I get the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/MasterNotRunningException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: HBaseConnection.  Program will exit.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunning is not available on the classpath.  You most likely have not set up the classpath to include the hadoop jar.  This can be as simple as a misspelling (and $HOME must be expanded).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did pass the correct classpath to the javac command, but since these Hadoop files are not on my global classpath, I was getting the error when I ran the java client using the java command. Passing in the classpath using "java -classpath $MYCLASSPATH HBaseConnection" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that native files are newly build in the system .

Wrong:

[hduser@master sbin]$ hadoop fs -ls /

16/07/17 15:38:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Found 5 items
drwxr-xr-x - hduser supergroup 0 2016-07-17 10:57 /cm

Correct

[hduser@master sbin]$ hadoop fs -ls /

Found 5 items

drwxr-xr-x - hduser supergroup 0 2016-07-17 10:57 /cm

in wrong configuration , follow below link to build it 
 http://www.myiphoneadventure.com/hardware/hadoop-build-native-library

For Hadoop 2.7.2 on RHL 6 GLIBC_2.12  , you can use 
https://github.com/sterin501/SecureHadoop/tree/master/native

For Complete hadoop 2.7.2 setup : 
http://wccandlinux.blogspot.in/2016/07/how-to-configure-hadoop-with-kerberos.html