# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/TableNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I was going to import data from local file to Hbase by using 'hbase.mapreduce.Import'.
I executed `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import News file:///Hbackup/News/` **on root**.

However, when I checked Hadoop container, I found an error happened. Here is the syslog of master node, which is same as another slave node:

```
2021-07-27 03:07:45,411 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1627349972787_0004_000001
2021-07-27 03:07:45,782 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens:
2021-07-27 03:07:45,782 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Kind: YARN_AM_RM_TOKEN, Service: , Ident: (appAttemptId { application_id { id: 4 cluster_timestamp: 1627349972787 } attemptId: 1 } keyId: -1057494481)
2021-07-27 03:07:45,934 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Using mapred newApiCommitter.
2021-07-27 03:07:46,605 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter set in config null
2021-07-27 03:07:46,661 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/TableNotFoundException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getOutputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1518)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1448)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 18 more
2021-07-27 03:07:46,665 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Unfortunately, I have searched this error on Baidu and Bing, and I cannot found useful articles, here is the most relavant one I found:
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/MasterNotRunningException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864520/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-hbase-masternotrunningexceptio)

Then I checked my Hadoop classpath, and **Hbase jars are already exist**.

```
root@master:~# $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath
/usr/tools/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/tools/hbase-2.3.5/lib/*:/usr/tools/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
```

In addition:

1. Here are the versions:

   Jdk: 1.8.0.291
   Zookeeper: 3.4.12
   Hadoop: 2.7.1
   Hbase: 2.3.5
2. I found another java program can write Hbase, so I believe Hbase works.

Now I have no idea about this error, what should I do to solve this?
Thanks for reading and answering.

Comment: are you sure `hbase-client.jar` is in your classpath on all cluster nodes?

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes, and they are chmod to 777.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException` says otherwise